What is the difference between Innermost Bound Circular Orbit (IBCO), Innermost Bound Spherical Orbit (IBSO), and Sphere Radius?
⚠ My question is related to Schwartzchild and Kerr Blackholes.
In a few words:
Innermost Bound Circular Orbit (IBCO):
It is the constant radius at which this circular orbit occurs at 1.5 Schwarzchild radii.
Sphere Radius:
It is the sphere around the black hole that formed from the possible orbital planes of light at the IBCO.
Innermost Bound Spherical Orbit (IBSO): __________________?
I didn't find any definition for IBSO except in the 'KerrGeodesics paclet on Mathematica'. But I didn't understand what is the difference between IBSO & Sphere Radius, especially since both of the terms are defined in the paclet but IBCO isn't in the paclet so maybe IBCO & IBSO are the same, but the abbreviation tell another thing.

I don't know about your paclet, but the different orbital radii are explained in Bardeen 1972

@Yukterez Thanks for your suggestion but this paper didn't answer my questions. I am searching for a definition to understand the difference.

I am not sure if these are the radii you are interested in, but Veritasium discusses some radii that matter in How to Understand the Image of a Black Hole

@mmesser314 Great video but he explained only ISCO & IBCO

As other answers have mentioned the innermost bound spherical orbit (IBSO) is a spherical orbit (I.e. an orbit with constant radius but varying inclination) with specific energy equal to one (I.e. just enough energy to reach infinity). (In Kerr) There are different IBSO radii depending on the maximal inclination of the orbit. In the KerrGeodesics Mathematica package this maximal inclination is parameterized by the variable $x$, which is $+1$ for prograde equatorial orbits, $x=-1$ for retrograde equatorial orbits, and $x=0$ for orbits that pass over the pole.
The innermost bound circular orbit (IBCO) is simply the special cases of an IBSO that is equatorial (I.e. $x=\pm 1$). (Note that In Schwarzschild the IBCO is at $4GM/c^2$, twice the Schwarzschild radius).
The photon sphere radius, is the radius where there exist spherical lightlike geodesics. For timeline spherical geodesics the specific energy goes to infinity at this radius. This radius again depends on the maximal  inclination, and the special case for equatorial orbits known as the photon ring or light ring). In Schwarzschild the light ring radius is at $3GM/c^2$.

A spherical orbit is an orbit around a Kerr black hole which remains at a constant radial coordinate $r$, but does not remain at a constant polar angle $\theta$.  Orbits such as this arise when the Carter constant is non-zero.
In general, these orbits do not close like circular orbits do, but instead fill out a non-zero fraction of the surface of constant $r$.  The distinction between spherical orbits and circular orbits only makes sense in a Kerr spacetime, not a Schwarzchild spacetime, since in Schwarzschild all orbits of constant $r$ are closed.
A readable discussion of these orbits, including references to past literature, can be found in Teo, Spherical Orbits around a Kerr Black Hole, Gen. Rel. Grav. 53 10 (2021).

For all possible orbits between the prograde and retrograde photon radius see here

Thanks @MichaelSeifert . What you suggested discussed the topic of spherical orbits but it didn't define Innermost Bound Spherical Orbit.

Thanks @Yukterez for your suggestion but it didn't answer my question.

@znp:  Bound orbits are defined in Section 2.1 of the article I linked, and stability is discussed in Section 4.1.

IBSO (Innermost Bound Spherical Orbit): the circular orbits that have the energy ε = 1.
